# DDL Create Trigger script fails

Tags: firebird, ddl, firebird2.5

A DDL script to create a trigger (source below) fails with 2 errors:

> Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
>   Dynamic SQL Error
>   -SQL error code = -104
>   -Unexpected end of command - line 3, column 44
>   After line 0 in file C:\CRMDemo\Database\DDL\Trigger_Orders.sql
>   Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
>   Dynamic SQL Error
>   -SQL error code = -104
>   -Token unknown - line 1, column 1
>   -end
>   At line 14 in file C:\CRMDemo\Database\DDL\Trigger_Orders.sql

(line 3, column 44 looks like it may be the closing parthesis).
I can't find any information about errors 42000 or -104.
The trigger is designed to assign a record number from a generator, which does exist. This trigger works properly in Interbase from the same script.
The only thing I can think of is that the column size, Integer, is incorrect for the value returned. But the documentation says the value may be truncated but should work for the expected value (1).

```
CREATE TRIGGER ORDERS_GENERATE_KEY FOR ORDERS ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 95 AS
begin
  NEW.ORDER_NR = GEN_ID(NEW_ORDER_NUMBER, 1);
end;
```

Firebird is ver 2.5.2, just downloaded. Windows 7. Database should be 32bit.

Comment: What utility do you use to execute the statement?

Comment: Just as background info: SQLstate 42000 is the very generic error 'syntax error or access rule violation' as defined in the SQL:2003 standard. Error -104 is the firebird equivalent of a general or syntax error (table 6.4 of the Interbase 6.0 Language reference (page 205-206) lists about 15 errors with that error code). Combined with the message 'Token unknown' (firebird error 335544634), it means there is a syntax error in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your statement using **isql** utility take sure that **SET TERM** operators are used:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE TRIGGER ORDERS_GENERATE_KEY FOR ORDERS 
  ACTIVE 
  BEFORE INSERT 
  POSITION 95 
AS
begin
  NEW.ORDER_NR = GEN_ID(NEW_ORDER_NUMBER, 1);
end
^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: That is probably the answer, I'll try it tomorrow. I am using isql. My other DDL scripts worked. Only the trigger scripts have a ";" within the sql create statement. I'm used to Interbase which dropped the Set Term a couple of versions ago. I've been removing them from my scripts for a while. I never thought about them here.